# Regular expression not working when put in an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to store regexes in a database but they're not working when used in a .sub(), even though the same regex works when used directly in .sub() as a string.

```
regex = Class.object.field  // Class.object is an active record containing "\w*\s\/\s"
mystring = "first / second"

mystring.sub(/#{regex}/, '')
// => nil

mystring.sub(/\w*\s\/\s/, '') 
// => second
```

Any insight appreciated!

Thanks,
Matt.

Editing to correct class/object terminology (thanks) & correcting my 2nd example as I had shown #{} wrapped around the working regex (cut & paste SNAFU).

Comment: What is the output when following averell's suggestion of `puts "My regexp: #{regexp}"`?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: It is not quite what kind of thing your `Class.object` is. If it's an ActiveRecord, it won't work.

**Edit:** You obviously found that the [problem is Rails escaping the regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580410).

An ActiveRecord cannot "contain" your regular expression directly; the regexp will be in one of the fields of your record. In which case you'd want to do something like `regexp = Class.object.field_containing_the_regexp`.

Even if that is not the case, I suspect that the problem is that your `regexp` is something other than a string. You can quickly test this by using

```
puts "My regexp: #{regexp}"
```

The string that you will see in the output will be the one that is used for the regexp.

Comment: "Edit: You obviously found that the problem is Rails escaping the regexp."

Thanks, but it was the opposite - I found out that rails console escapes the output, and so that wasn't the problem even though it appeared to be, hence this post. Anyway, I've solved it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A String is not a Regexp.  You have to create a Regexp object first.

```
regex = Regexp.new("\w*\s\/\s")
```

Comment: No, you don't:

    `/#{some_string}/`

will create a regexp using the given string. In fact `/something/` is the same as `Regexp.new("something")`.

Comment: Hmm..  I completely missed that in his code.  I guess I'm off on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my regexp didn't cater for all cases - \w didn't account for symbols. After checking in rails console, and seeing the screwey escaping I was alreasdy half-way down the wrong track.

Thanks for the help.